# A JavaScript Error Occurred in the Main Process on Windows OS

Tags: import, electron, expo, electron-builder, electron-packager

I am working on an electron.js Project. When in run `yarn electron-builder build` it creates `.exe` file.
when I install that app on Windows it throws an error that is

> A JavaScript Error Occurred in the Main Process

On package.json

```
"devDependencies": {    
   "electron-builder": "^22.14.13",
   "electron": "^6.0.12",
   "@expo/electron-adapter": "^0.0.55",
}

"dependencies": {
    "expo": "~44.0.6",
}
```

The Issue is that when I run on local it's not given any error on the console.

[image]

Suggest me how to resolve this issue.

**index.js**

```
import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';
import App from './App';

// registerRootComponent calls AppRegistry.registerComponent('main', () => App);
// It also ensures that whether you load the app in Expo Go or in a native build,
// the environment is set up appropriately
registerRootComponent(App);
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm working through the same issue now